# Cannot run django function

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial on youtube on learning Django.The person i am following is using a macbook and i am on windows.The person run this command in his terminal trying to start a new project and he entered this code

```
django-admin startproject storefront
```

and he was successfull.But when i tried it for windows it gave an error. I googled the error and got a solution

```
python -m django startproject storefront
```

Then the man wanted to run the server using this code

```
manage.py runserver
```

and he was successfull but when i tied on windows it gave this error

```
mange.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

Comment: You may have to install python on your windows computer, maybe follow djangos install instructions before relying on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep using `python` as the first word.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Your terminal has to know, that you want interprete `manage.py` as Python program.